# How to track objects "called" inside a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Question:

- I need to know the records' attributes that have been called inside a block (say I need something like the following):

  ```
  def my_custom_method(&block)
    some_method_that_starts_tracking

    block.call

    some_method_that_stops_tracking

    puts some_method_that_returns_called_records_attributes
    do_something_about(some_method_that_returns_called_records_attributes)
  end

  my_custom_method { somecodethatcallsauthorofbook1andemailandfirstnameofuser43 }

  # this is the `puts` output above (just as an example)
  # => {
  #      #<Book id:1...>  => [:author],
  #      #<User id:43...> => [:email, :first_name]
  #    }
  ```
- code inside the block can be anything
- Specifically, I meant to track any instance of a subclass of `ApplicationRecord`, so it can be instance of any models like `Book`, `User`, etc...

### Attempts:

- From my understanding, this is similar to how `rspec` works when a method is expected to be called. That it somehow tracks any calls of that method.  So, my initial attempt is to do something like the following (which does not yet fully work):

  ```
  def my_custom_method(&block)
    called_records_attributes = {}

    ApplicationRecord.descendants.each do |klass|
      klass.class_eval do
        attribute_names.each do |attribute_name|
          define_method(attribute_name) do
            called_records_attributes[self] ||= []
            called_records_attributes[self] << attribute_name
            self[attribute_name]
          end
        end
      end
    end

    block.call

    # the above code will work but at this point, I don't know how to clean the methods that were defined above, as the above define_methods should only be temporary

    puts called_records_attributes
  end

  my_custom_method { Book.find_by(id: 1).title }
  # => {
  #      #<Book id: 1...> => ['title']
  #    }
  ```

  - the `.descendants` above probably is not a good idea because Rails use `autoload` if I'm not mistaken
  - as already said above in the comment, I do not know how to remove these "defined_methods" that are just supposed to be only temporary for the duration of this "block".
  - furthermore, my code above would probably have overriden the "actual" attribute getters of the models, if ever any has been already defined, which is bad.

### Background:

- I am writing a gem [live_record](https://github.com/jrpolidario/live_record/) which I am adding a new feature that will allow a developer to just simply write something like

  ```
  <!-- app/views/application.html.erb -->
  <body>
    <%= live_record_sync { @book.some_custom_method_about_book } %>
  </body>
  ```

... which will render `@book.some_custom_method_about_book` as-is on the page, but at the same time the `live_record_sync` wrapper method would take note of all the attributes that have been called inside that block (i.e. inside `some_custom_method_about_book` the `@book.title` is called), and then it sets these attributes as the block's own "dependencies", in which later when that specific book's attribute has been updated, I can already also update directly the HTML page of which this attribute is a "dependency" as like specified just above. I am aware that this is not an accurate solution, but I'd like to open up my chances by experimenting on this first.

-- **Rails 5**

Comment: _Hint:_ `rspec` is open source.

Comment: @mudasobwa oh yes I meant to do that. But I was just hoping first if it'd be faster to ask this first before I go diving into the code, and for future readers who might be asking the same question (as it seems that there is no stackoverflow question like this yet). But thank you! :) I'm reading rspec code right now simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I believe this is just a mediocre solution, but hopefully helps anyone with the same problem.

I tried reading **rspec** source code, but because I couldn't easily comprehend what is happening under the hood, and that it occurred to me that **rspec**'s (i.e.) `expect(Book.first).to receive(:title)` is different from what I really want because the methods there are already specified (i.e. `:title`), while what I want is to track ANY methods that are attributes, so because of these two reasons I skipped reading further, and attempted my own solution, which hopefully did somehow work; see below.

Note that I am using `Thread` local-storage here, so this code should be thread-safe (untested yet).

```
# lib/my_tracker.rb
class MyTracker
  Thread.current[:my_tracker_current_tracked_records] = {}

  attr_accessor :tracked_records

  class << self
    def add_to_tracked_records(record, attribute_name)
      Thread.current[:my_tracker_current_tracked_records][{model: record.class.name.to_sym, record_id: record.id}] ||=  []
      Thread.current[:my_tracker_current_tracked_records][{model: record.class.name.to_sym, record_id: record.id}] << attribute_name
    end
  end

  def initialize(block)
    @block = block
  end

  def call_block_while_tracking_records
    start_tracking

    @block_evaluated_value = @block.call
    @tracked_records = Thread.current[:my_tracker_current_tracked_records]

    stop_tracking
  end

  def to_s
    @block_evaluated_value
  end

  # because I am tracking record-attributes, and you might want to track a different object / method, then you'll need to write your own `prepend` extension (look for how to use `prepend` in ruby)
  module ActiveRecordExtensions
    def _read_attribute(attribute_name)
      if Thread.current[:my_tracker_current_tracked_records] && !Thread.current[:my_tracker_is_tracking_locked] && self.class < ApplicationRecord
        # I added this "lock" to prevent infinite loop inside `add_to_tracked_records` as I am calling the record.id there, which is then calling this _read_attribute, and then loops.
        Thread.current[:my_tracker_is_tracking_locked] = true
        ::MyTracker.add_to_tracked_records(self, attribute_name)
        Thread.current[:my_tracker_is_tracking_locked] = false
      end
      super(attribute_name)
    end
  end

  module Helpers
    def track_records(&block)
      my_tracker = MyTracker.new(block)
      my_tracker.call_block_while_tracking_records
      my_tracker
    end
  end

  private

  def start_tracking
    Thread.current[:my_tracker_current_tracked_records] = {}
  end

  def stop_tracking
    Thread.current[:my_tracker_current_tracked_records] = nil
  end
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  prepend MyTracker::ActiveRecordExtensions
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_view) do
  include MyTracker::Helpers
end

ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
  include MyTracker::Helpers
end
```

### Usage Example

**some_controller.rb**

```
book = Book.find_by(id: 1)
user = User.find_by(id: 43)

my_tracker = track_records do
  book.title
  if user.created_at == book.created_at
    puts 'same date'
  end
  'thisisthelastlineofthisblockandthereforewillbereturned'
end

puts my_tracker.class
# => #<MyTracker ... >

puts my_tracker.tracked_records
# => {
#      {model: :Book, record_id: 1} => ['title', 'created_at'],
#      {model: :User, record_id: 43} => ['created_at']
#    }

puts my_tracker
# => 'thisisthelastlineofthisblockandthereforewillbereturned'
# notice that `puts my_tracker` above prints out the block itself
# this is because I defined `.to_s` above.
# I need this `.to_s` so I can immediately print the block as-is in the views.
# see example below
```

**some_view.html.erb**

```
<%= track_records { current_user.email } %>
```

*P.S. Maybe it's better that I wrap this up as a gem. If you're interested, let me know*